# In Twitter Bootstrap How can I fix my menu bar on the top while scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to fix my menu bar at top while scrolling in twitter bootstrap.

It was similar to this website: http://www.jobsite.co.uk/

Here is my code:

```
<div class="navbar" id="top">
     <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
     <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
     <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
     <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
     <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
     <li><a href="#">Link3</a></li>
     <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
     <li><a href="#">Link4s</a></li>
     <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
     <li><a href="#">Link5</a></li>
     <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Link6<b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
     </li>
     </ul>
     </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed to top

Add `.navbar-fixed-top` and remember to account for the hidden area underneath it by adding at least 40px padding to the `<body>`. Be sure to add this after the core Bootstrap CSS and before the optional responsive CSS.

from http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/components.html#navbar

Answer (score 0):

```
#mainNav{position:fiexed;width:100%;}
```